# Change comment size relative to original size of fill picture in Excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, comments, ms-office

Trying to write a VBA excel macro that will allow me to insert a picture as a pop-up on mouseover of a cell.

I'm accomplishing this by inserting a comment in the cell and setting the comment's fill to be a specified picture.

I would like the picture to maintain its original scaling

After setting the comment to use the picture as a fill background, I can manually right-click the cell, click edit comment, right-click the comment, go to the "size" tab, select "Relative to original picture size" checkbox, and set scale height and size to be 100%, which achieves the desired effect, as shown below:[image]

Recording a macro to see what the VBA to replicate this is results in nothing being recorded.

Using the `targetComment.Shape.ScaleHeight 1, msoTrue` results in an error:

```
Run-time error '-2147024891 (80070005)':
The RelativeToOriginalSize argument applies only to a picture or an OLE object
```

Here is a screenshot of the VBA code that generates this error:

[image]

Does anyone know how to access what is in the dialog box via VBA???

Comment: I'd use hyperlinks instead of comment: http://optionexplicitvba.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/rollover-b8-ov1.html, then you can use the target arguement to access the cell properties such as height

Comment: @Absinthe I don't think this will work for me since I want the picture that gets displayed to be anchored/live in a shape instead of a cell (that way the adjacent cells can be regular size even though they display a large picture on mouseover).  I also can't use the adjacent cells in my use case (they are part of a table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a comment to show an image with scaling can be done. The trick is to calculate the scaling factor yourself and apply it to the image. I've used the [Windows Image Acquisition Automation Layer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630827(v=vs.85).aspx) to access the [image file's dimensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630506(v=vs.85).aspx).

The example below accesses a JPG image in my Temp directory and adds it to a cell's comment with appropriate scaling.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    '--- delete any existing comment just for testing
    If Not Range("C5").Comment Is Nothing Then
        Range("C5").Comment.Delete
    End If
    InsertCommentWithImage Range("C5"), "C:\Temp\laptop.jpg", 1#
End Sub

Sub InsertCommentWithImage(imgCell As Range, _
                           imgPath As String, _
                           imgScale As Double)
    '--- first check if the image file exists in the
    '    specified path
    If Dir(imgPath) <> vbNullString Then
        If imgCell.Comment Is Nothing Then
            imgCell.AddComment
        End If

        '--- establish a Windows Image Acquisition Automation object
        '    to get the image's dimensions
        Dim imageObj As Object
        Set imageObj = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
        imageObj.LoadFile (imgPath)

        Dim width As Long
        Dim height As Long
        width = imageObj.width
        height = imageObj.height

        '--- simple scaling that keeps the image's
        '    original aspect ratio
        With imgCell.Comment
            .Shape.Fill.UserPicture imgPath
            .Shape.height = height * imgScale
            .Shape.width = width * imgScale
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: interesting solution, I didn't know about the WIA utility.  Nice one!  I guess a more cross-platform friendly solution would be to disable screenupdating, insert the picture as a picture shape, query its dimensions, then delete it and proceed as in your example manually setting Shape.height and Shape.width parameters of the comment

Comment: If cross platform is part of the goal, then yes adding a (screen disabled) shape would certainly get you the dimensions. The point is that all the scaling is done yourself, instead of using `ScaleHeight`. And so the decision to maintain the original aspect ratio is also up to you.